# How can java class send its parameters on need basis?

Tags: java, oop, java-7

I am new to Java.
I have CardDetails class which is a return type of my getCardDetails method.
Now, the scenario is I have common class(CardDetails) to return a result to my UI from method getCardDetails().

```
public class CardDetails {
    String cardNumber;
    String cardCode;
    String cardStatus;
    String debitCardPrimaryAccountNumber;
    String creditCardDescription;
    String creditCardActionCode;
}
```

If you see the class last fields creditCardDescription and creditCardActionCode are of credit card & debitCardPrimaryAccountNumber is only specific to DebitCard.
Now, which concept of OOPs I can use so that in case of Credit Card my class object would be:

```
public class CardDetails {
    String cardNumber;
    String cardCode;
    String cardStatus;
    String creditCardDescription;
    String creditCardActionCode;
}
```

and for Debit card it would be:

```
public class CardDetails {
    String cardNumber;
    String cardCode;
    String cardStatus;
    String debitCardPrimaryAccountNumber;
}
```

As my return type would always be CardDetails class.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Simply have different subclasses for `DebitCardDetails` and `CreditCardDetails` and the (now abstract) base class `CardDetails` only has the properties that both/all subclasses share.

Comment: Will it be possible to share some sample code. Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: I think now would be a good time to read that chapter about *Inheritance* in your textbook :)

Comment: Can you please accept the right answer? Thanks mate

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so what you are trying to achieve is typical *inheritance*. You need a super class CardDetails and two more specific-sub-classes CreditCardDetails and DebitCardDetails which will extend the CardDetails class.

Here your superclass Card:

```
public class CardDetails {
    String cardNumber;
    String cardCode;
    String cardStatus;
}
```

Here are your two sub-classes:

```
public class CreditCardDetails extends CardDetails {
    String creditCardDescription;
    String creditCardActionCode;
}

public class DebitCardDetails extends CardDetails {
    String debitCardPrimaryAccountNumber;
}
```

To better understand the inheritance concept, it means that CreditCardDetails and DebitCardDetails both inherit (extend) from the CardDetails class, meaning that they contain all the attributes and methods of the superclass in this case CardDetails. Furthermore, your subclasses (CreditCardDetails and DebitCardDetails) have additional attributes and probably additional methods as you may add them.

Let me know if that helped. :)

Comment: Thanks Tomino,
Is there any way we can use interfaces here ?

Comment: There is a way, but is there a reason? @user2746466

Comment: So interfaces are more of a contract that you will implement some methods, so probably not ideal in this context. But abstract class may be a good option for you. Please go check out more on official docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Answer (score -1):

```java
public class CardDetails {
    String cardNumber;
    String cardCode;
    String cardStatus;
}

public class CreditCard extends CardDetails {
    String creditCardDescription;
    String creditCardActionCode;
}

public class DebitCard extends CardDetails {
    String debitCardPrimaryAccountNumber;
}
```

Comment: A good answer would also contain some explanatory words. Just dumping the code here doesn't really teach much.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers, there is one basically the same answer above you. Also, consider some explanation for your future answers.